# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'img'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to perform an if elif statement that displays items in multiple frames using tkinter.  The first frame is just a standard frame with radio buttons for each state to select the state you want to see information on it.  When you click on the Get State Info button, it is to then populate state data into the state information frame and the state flag into a state flag frame.  The flags show up correctly but I am receiving the following errors when I execute my code.

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "dir\WIP.py", line 297, in getstateinfo
    alflag()
  File "dir\WIP.py", line 283, in alflag
    show()
  File "dir\WIP.py", line 276, in show
    show=show.img
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'img'
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "dir\WIP.py", line 314, in getstateinfo
    show.img
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'img'
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "dir\WIP.py", line 305, in getstateinfo
    show.img
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'img'
```

How do you resolve the issue above.
Please note DIR is where my code is stored on my PC.  I have masked it.

Code:

```
#imports
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
from functools import partial
import webbrowser
import tkinter as tk

from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image
import os

#create window object
window=Tk()
window.configure(background='black')

#define windown title
window.title("Useful information about each state of the United States of America")

#define frames
#define state selection frame
f0=Frame(window, padx=12, bd=12, width=600, height=300, relief=RIDGE)
f0.grid(row=0, column=1)

#define exit frame
f1=Frame(window, padx=12, bd=12, width=600, height=300, relief=RIDGE)
f1.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E)

#define state flag description frame
f4=Frame(window, padx=12, bd=12, width=600, height=300, relief=RIDGE)
f4.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

#define state flag image frame
f2=Frame(window, padx=12, bd=12, width=600, height=300, relief=RIDGE)
f2.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

#define US graphics frame
f3=Frame(window, padx=12, bd=12, bg="black", width=600, height=300, relief=RIDGE)
f3.grid(row=0, column=0)

#define state flag description frame
f6=Frame(window, padx=12, bd=12, width=600, height=300, relief=RIDGE)
f6.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

#define results frame
f5=Frame(window, padx=12, bd=12, width=600, height=300, relief=RIDGE)
f5.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

#define results frame
f7=Frame(window, padx=12, bd=12, width=600, height=200, relief=RIDGE)
f7.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)

#define exit app
def exitapp():
    exitmsg=messagebox.askyesno("Exit Program","Do you want to exit the program?")
    if exitmsg>0:
        window.destroy()
        return

#define reset input and output
def resetinout():
    resetinout=inputvalue.set("")
    resetinout=var.set(0)
    o1.delete('1.0', END)
    o1.insert(END,
    "INSTRUCTIONS:\n1) Select the radio button from the State list above\n2) Click on the Get State 
Info Button\n")
    for widget in f2.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()

#define about
def about():
    messagebox.showinfo('About the useful information for each state in the USA',
    'Created by:\nMy Name\ninfo\ninfo\ninfo')
    
#define menubar
menu = Menu(window)
window.config(menu=menu)

file = Menu(menu)
file.add_command(label='Exit', command=exitapp)
menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file)

help = Menu(menu)
help.add_command(label='About', command=about)
menu.add_cascade(label='Help', menu=help)

#define labels
l1=Label(f0, text="Select a State:", bg= 'blue', fg='white', font='times 24 bold')
l1.grid(row=0,column=0)

l2=Label(f4, text="State Flag:", bg= 'white', fg='black', font='times 24 bold')
l2.grid(row=0,column=0)

l2=Label(f6, text="State Information:", bg= 'white', fg='black', font='times 24 bold')
l2.grid(row=0,column=0)

#define entries
#input value
inputvalue=StringVar()
window.val = StringVar()
var=IntVar()
window.var=IntVar()

#define radio buttons

window.r1=Radiobutton(f0, text="Alabama", variable=var, value=1, 
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=W)

window.r2=Radiobutton(f0, text="Alaska", variable=var, value=2, 
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=W)

window.r3=Radiobutton(f0, text="Arizona", variable=var, value=3,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=W)

window.r4=Radiobutton(f0, text="Arkansas", variable=var, value=4,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=W)

window.r5=Radiobutton(f0, text="California", variable=var, value=5,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=1, row=5, sticky=W)

window.r6=Radiobutton(f0, text="Colorado", variable=var, value=6,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=1, row=6, sticky=W)

window.r7=Radiobutton(f0, text="Connecticut", variable=var, value=7,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=1, row=7, sticky=W)

window.r8=Radiobutton(f0, text="Delaware", variable=var, value=8,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=1, row=8, sticky=W)

window.r9=Radiobutton(f0, text="Florida", variable=var, value=9,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=1, row=9, sticky=W)

window.r10=Radiobutton(f0, text="Georgia", variable=var, value=10,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=1, row=10, sticky=W)

window.r11=Radiobutton(f0, text="Hawaii", variable=var, value=11,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=W)

window.r12=Radiobutton(f0, text="Idaho", variable=var, value=12,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=W)

window.r13=Radiobutton(f0, text="Illinois", variable=var, value=13,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=W)

window.r14=Radiobutton(f0, text="Indiana", variable=var, value=14,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=2, row=4, sticky=W)

window.r15=Radiobutton(f0, text="Iowa", variable=var, value=15,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=2, row=5, sticky=W)

window.r16=Radiobutton(f0, text="Kansas", variable=var, value=16,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=2, row=6, sticky=W)

window.r17=Radiobutton(f0, text="Kentucky", variable=var, value=17,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=2, row=7, sticky=W)

window.r18=Radiobutton(f0, text="Louisiana", variable=var, value=18,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=2, row=8, sticky=W)

window.r19=Radiobutton(f0, text="Maine", variable=var, value=19,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=2, row=9, sticky=W)

window.r20=Radiobutton(f0, text="Maryland", variable=var, value=20,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=2, row=10, sticky=W)

window.r21=Radiobutton(f0, text="Massachusetts", variable=var, value=21,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=W)

window.r22=Radiobutton(f0, text="Michigan", variable=var, value=22,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=W)

window.r23=Radiobutton(f0, text="Minnesota", variable=var, value=23,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W)

window.r24=Radiobutton(f0, text="Mississippi", variable=var, value=24,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=3, row=4, sticky=W)

window.r25=Radiobutton(f0, text="Missouri", variable=var, value=25,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=3, row=5, sticky=W)

window.r26=Radiobutton(f0, text="Montana", variable=var, value=26,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=3, row=6, sticky=W)

window.r27=Radiobutton(f0, text="Nebraska", variable=var, value=27,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=3, row=7, sticky=W)

window.r28=Radiobutton(f0, text="Nevada", variable=var, value=28,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=3, row=8, sticky=W)

window.r29=Radiobutton(f0, text="New Hampshire", variable=var, value=29,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=3, row=9, sticky=W)

window.r30=Radiobutton(f0, text="New Jersey", variable=var, value=30,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=3, row=10, sticky=W)

window.r31=Radiobutton(f0, text="New Mexico", variable=var, value=31,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=4, row=1, sticky=W)

window.r32=Radiobutton(f0, text="New York", variable=var, value=32,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=4, row=2, sticky=W)

window.r33=Radiobutton(f0, text="North Carolina", variable=var, value=33,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=4, row=3, sticky=W)

window.r34=Radiobutton(f0, text="North Dakota", variable=var, value=34,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=4, row=4, sticky=W)

window.r35=Radiobutton(f0, text="Ohio", variable=var, value=35,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=4, row=5, sticky=W)

window.r36=Radiobutton(f0, text="Oklahoma", variable=var, value=36,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=4, row=6, sticky=W)

window.r37=Radiobutton(f0, text="Oregon", variable=var, value=37,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=4, row=7, sticky=W)

window.r38=Radiobutton(f0, text="Pennsylvania", variable=var, value=38,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=4, row=8, sticky=W)

window.r39=Radiobutton(f0, text="Rhode Island", variable=var, value=39,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=4, row=9, sticky=W)

window.r40=Radiobutton(f0, text="South Carolina", variable=var, value=40,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=4, row=10, sticky=W)

window.r41=Radiobutton(f0, text="South Dakota", variable=var, value=41,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=5, row=1, sticky=W)

window.r42=Radiobutton(f0, text="Tennessee", variable=var, value=42,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=5, row=2, sticky=W)

window.r43=Radiobutton(f0, text="Texas", variable=var, value=43,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=5, row=3, sticky=W)

window.r44=Radiobutton(f0, text="Utah", variable=var, value=44,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=5, row=4, sticky=W)

window.r45=Radiobutton(f0, text="Vermont", variable=var, value=45,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=5, row=5, sticky=W)

window.r46=Radiobutton(f0, text="Virginia", variable=var, value=46,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=5, row=6, sticky=W)

window.r47=Radiobutton(f0, text="Washington", variable=var, value=47,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=5, row=7, sticky=W)

window.r48=Radiobutton(f0, text="West Virginia", variable=var, value=48,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=5, row=8, sticky=W)

window.r49=Radiobutton(f0, text="Wisconsin", variable=var, value=49,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=5, row=9, sticky=W)

window.r50=Radiobutton(f0, text="Wyoming", variable=var, value=50,
                      font=("times", 12, "bold"), pady=6, padx=5).grid(column=5, row=10, sticky=W)

#define images
#US Map
imgus = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("US-Capitals-Map.jpg"))
panel = Label(f3, image = imgus)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "no")

#def show
def show():
    global show
    show=show.img

#Alabama State Flag
def alflag():
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Flag_of_Alabama.svg.png"))
    panel = Label(f2, image = img)
    panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "none", expand = "no")
    show()
    
#define get state information
def getstateinfo():
    if var.get() == 1:
        for widget in f2.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        o1.delete('1.0', END)
        o1.insert(END, "State: Alabama\n")
        o1.insert(END, "State Number: 22\n")
        o1.insert(END, "Year of Statehood: 1819\n")
        o1.insert(END, "State Capital: Montgomery\n")
        resetinout=inputvalue.set("")
        resetinout=var.set(0)
        alflag()

    elif var.get() == 2:
        for widget in f2.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Flag_of_Alaska.svg.png"))
        panel = Label(f2, image = img)
        panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "none", expand = "no")
        show.img
        resetinout=var.set(0)     

    elif var.get() == 13:
        for widget in f2.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Flag_of_Illinois.svg.png"))
        panel = Label(f2, image = img)
        panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "none", expand = "no")
        show.img
        resetinout=var.set(0)

#define buttons

b1=Button(f0,text="Get State Info", bg='gray', fg='white', font="times 12 bold",
          width=24, padx=12, bd=12, relief=RIDGE, command = getstateinfo)
b1.grid(row=12,column=0)

b2=Button(f0,text="Reset", bg='gray', fg='white',font="times 12 bold",
          width=24, padx=12, bd=12, relief=RIDGE, command = resetinout)
b2.grid(row=11,column=0)

b3=Button(f1,text="Exit", bg='gray', fg='white',font="times 12 bold",
          width=24, padx=12, bd=12, relief=RIDGE, command = exitapp)
b3.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=E)

b4=Button(f7,text="State Capital Map", bg='gray', fg='white',font="times 12 bold",
          width=24, padx=12, bd=12, relief=RIDGE)#, command = statecapmap)
b4.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=E)

#define output box
o1=Text(f5, width=75, height=10, font="times 12 bold", bd=12, relief=RIDGE)
o1.grid(row=1,column=0)
o1.insert(END,
"INSTRUCTIONS:\n1) Select the radio button from the State list above\n2) Click on the Get State Info 
Button\n")

window.mainloop()
```

Is there an easy fix for this?  Please advise.

Comment: What do  you mean by `show.img`

Comment: This is the only way I am able to get the image to show up in frame f2.  If I remove that, no image shows up in that frame.

Comment: You created three individual menus here, i thought creating one was enough and you could `add_cascade`

Comment: but will that solve the error message I am receiving?

Comment: i dont know what `show.img` is. I think it will refer to your `show()` that you defined